# Personal framework project website

Tags: selenium, test-automation-framework, c#

I am a selenium C# developer, and have just recently conducted an interview with a company. During this process I was asked a lot of questions about "hypothetical" framework questions, and how I would architect a system of tests for a product. Towards the end of the interview I was asked if I could showcase a framework that I have implemented in the past, and of course with non-disclosure agreements I am unable to share that information. The interviewer seemed disappointed that I didn't have one created that he could look at, and I feel as though the interview went downhill from there. I have decided to create my own framework so that I can show potential employers my work. The question that I have is:

> **What is a website that I can test(create the framework around), that is not my employers?**

I am just wondering what sites other professionals in this field have used for there own personal frameworks.

Comment: Not obvious what you are asking: (1) On which website to showcase your portfolio code? (2) What website to test? (any will be fine) (3) Which framework to use to create your portfolio showcase project? (4) Something else?

Comment: Edited, hopefully that makes my question more "Obvious". More or less, what site can I use to test. That has a fair bit of complexity to showcase in the framework.

Comment: Instead of doing a site-specific question I would think about implementing a library that is domain/project independent. In Java examples are like Awaitility for asynchronous checks, Rest-Assured or Retrofit for testing REST services. I'm sure there are similar in C#. It doesn't even has to be something so big. For instance, you don't like the way soft assertions are implemented in nUnit? Implement them your way and show how you use it in your projects. Looking from this perspective, I think this question deserves re-opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might refer to Joe Strazzere's post in [this similar question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/what-is-a-good-website-to-hack-around-using-selenium/8769#8769) about not using Selenium on public websites without authorization.

My suggestion would be one of these two websites, which are available specifically to run Selenium tests on:

- http://store.demoqa.com/
- http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/

They might not be the most difficult, although the second one has a nice variety of different types of inputs and challenges. I'm also experimenting with a Selenium framework, and use that site to test everything on.

(Frankly, the interviewers are most interested in the **framework**, not in how you click through a random website... If you can show a decent solution with clean code, pageobjects, data-driven examples, ... that's much more important than having a complex website.)

Answer (score 1):

So IIUC, what website to write the tests for?

Any website accessible by public is OK.

- Adding new blog posts in blogger.com.
- Checking "where is the George" http://www.wheresgeorge.com/
- Online ordering from Staples.com or ordering pizza.
- tracking a ticker price for stock, notify on up or down.

Anything you care about.

Make sure that website had decent locators for the controls. Or maybe show your XPATH skills with some website which does not.

Answer (score 0):

This site has pages that are good for exercising the various types of web elements: https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/